# Python - How many are just a single word in a list

Tags: python

How do I get total number of single words in a list. There are 8 elements in a list below. However, some elements have more than single words in them 'apples are delicious', how to do I just capture just the number of single word from list?

```
list = ['apples', 'apples', 'apples are delicious', 'oranges', 'fruits', 'kiwi', 'fruit festivals', 'festivals']

len(list) # total number of elements in a list
list.count("apples") # only counts a specific word but not a element single words

# total 8 elements 
# how many are only 1 word?
# results: 6/8 are 1 words
```

Comment: `[i for i in L if len(i.split()) == 1]` should find you only single words.  You should avoid naming lists `list` as it overrides a builtin

Comment: @user3483203 this gives list of single words, very helpful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X = ['apples', 'apples', 'apples are delicious', 'oranges', 'fruits', 'kiwi', 'fruit festivals', 'festivals']
ar = [i for i in X if len(i.split()) == 1]
print(len(ar))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> lst = ['apples', 'apples', 'apples are delicious', 'oranges', 'fruits', 'kiwi', 'fruit festivals', 'festivals']
>>> len([w for w in lst if ' ' not in w])
6
```

By the way, avoid name `list` for variables as `list` is a builtin

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way would be:

```
count = sum(1 for x in lst if ' ' not in x)
```

- it doesn't use `split` so it doesn't create a new list
- it doesn't create a list just to apply `len` on it

it just adds 1 every time the generator comprehension finds that space isn't in the word

Answer (score 2):

Using `filter` function:

```
l = ['apples', 'apples', 'apples are delicious', 'oranges', 'fruits', 'kiwi', 'fruit festivals', 'festivals']

count = len(list(filter(lambda v: len(v.split()) == 1, l)))

print(count)
```

Output:

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's list comprehension -

```
fruits = ['apples', 'apples', 'apples are delicious', 'oranges', 'fruits', 'kiwi', 'fruit festivals', 'festivals']
result1 = len([i for in in fruits if len(i.split('')) == 1])
result2 = len([i for in in fruits if ' ' not in i])
```

Can be done with regex also -

```
import re
result3 = len([i for in in fruits if not re.match('\s', i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are indeed correct.

However you may not want to rely only on whitespaces to define whether a string is multiwords or not. I mean `apple/orange` is two words but will not be tokenized as such if you just check whether there are whitespaces inside. You might want to use `\w+` in regex inside.

Agreeing also with other comments about `split()` creating a list per entry (and also having to loop over the whole entry string), as well as `len` implicitly creating a list of all the results as well, here is my proposition:

```
import re
single_word = re.compile(r'^\w+$')

lst = ['apples', 'apples', 'apples are delicious', 'oranges', 'fruits', 'kiwi', 'fruit festivals', 'festivals']
print(sum(1 for w in lst if re.match(single_word, w)))

>>>> 6
```

This way you loop over the list once and sum on the fly. And per entry you loop over it only once as well and stop as soon as a non-word character is found. This is probably one of the fastest simple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple logical way to do the same:

```
count=0
for word in l:
  if ' ' in word:
    count=count+1
print(count)
```

Here I simply using in statement to check spaces.